# Duvida Pesquisar Registro VBA

Tags: vba

Estou com um problema na minha aplicação, segue:

No meu excel tenho uma *sheet* chamada parâmetros, nela tenho duas colunas, onde a coluna A é o nome do parâmetro e a coluna B é o valor do parâmetro.

Criei um método chamado `BuscarParametro` onde eu recebo o nome do parâmetro (coluna A) e devo retornar o valor do parâmetro (coluna B).

O método procura na coluna A o valor que recebeu por parâmetro, encontrando ele pega o numero da linha e concatena com a coluna B para saber o valor do parâmetro.

Minhas duvidas seria:

1. Tem uma forma melhor e mais eficiente de fazer isso?
2. No código do método, não retorna nada no método `Find`, mesmo existindo valor na planilha

Segue abaixo o método:

```
Public Function BuscarParametro(Parametro As String) As String

    Dim Resultado As Range
    Dim Posicao As String

    Set Resultado = Sheets("parametros").Range("A1:A9999").Find(Parametro, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

    If Resultado Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    Posicao = "B" & Resultado.Row

    BuscarParametro = Sheets("parametros").Range(Posicao)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar usar a fórmula `VLOOKUP` (ou [`PROCV`](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/PROCV-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-PROCV-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) em pt-br) para encontrar o dado requerido na mesma linha, na coluna B.

Sintaxe:

```
VLookup(parametro_que_quero_encontrar,
        range_que_quero_procurar, 
        retornar_valor_de_qual_coluna_do_range, 
        procurar_valor_aprox_ou_exato)
```

Veja aplicada no código:

```
Public Function BuscarParametro(param As String) As String

    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup _
            (param, Range("A:B"), 2, 0)

    BuscarParametro = result

End Function

Sub busca_param()

    MsgBox (BuscarParametro("item5"))

End Sub
```

E o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Otimo! Funcionou, obrigado dot.Py!!

Comment: @bbariotti, que bom! Já que essa resposta resolveu o seu problema, sugiro que [aceite a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para marcá-la como respondida.

Comment: Feito @dot.Py !!!

Aproveitando, se possivel, poderia me ajudar com essa outra duvida:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208915/consultar-dados-com-filtro-vba