# Consultar Dados Com Filtro VBA

Tags: vba, filter

Galera, boa noite

Estou com um problema em VBA, podem me ajudar, por favor. Segue:

Tenho um excel com a Sheet1 e a Sheet2. Na Sheet2 tenho um lista de clientes onde tenho os seguintes dados: Nome, Cidade e Idade.

[image: Exemplo dos dados]

Em VBA, preciso copiar os dados da Sheet2 e colar na Sheet1 com base em alguns filtros, por exemplo onde a Cidade seja igual a "São Paulo".

Exemplo do resultado seria, na Sheet1, copiar os dados onde a cidade seja igual a São Paulo, então teria João e Manuel.

Alguns pontos que podem ser um empecilho:
1 - Eu não sei a quantidade de linhas do cadastro da Sheet2. Por exmplo, conforme imagem acima, o cadastro tem 4 registros, porém poderia tem 200. Nesse caso eu não sei previamente a quantidade de linhas que tem.

2 - No cadastro, pode ser que entre dois registros possua linhas em branco.Por exemplo, entre o registro do Manoel e do Carlos, tem uma linha em branco.

Obrigado.

Comment: Sugiro que coloque uma imagem de exemplo, para facilitar o entendimento de como seus dados estão dispostos na planilha..

Comment: Não entendi muito bem.. você gostaria de criar uma macro onde vc passe um filtro e ela copie os dados da plan2 pra a plan1?

Comment: Editei a pergunta colocando uma imagem de como estaria os dados. No caso eu não sei quantos registros tem na Sheet2 e também pode contem linhas em branco entre os registros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui aqui galera.

Descobrindo a ultima linha preenchida, com o comando abaixo, independente das linhas em branco e da quantidade de linha deu certo:

```
UltimaLinha = PlanilhaOrigem.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

E para o filtro utilizei os comandos abaixo:

```
PlanilhaOrigem.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(LocalOrigem).Select    
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<300"    
Range(LocalOrigem).CurrentRegion.Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar à questão, como outros podem ter o mesmo problema. Eu abordaria de forma diferente. Primeiro iria para a segunda aba e faria um loop independente do número de linhas e da presença de linhas em branco, como já foi respondido pelo autor, mas sem usar o filtro.

```
Sub copyFromSheet2()

Dim lngUltimaLinha As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim strNomeCidade As String

lngUltimaLinha = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row

'Aqui vai o nome da cidade que deseja, pode ser por InputBox também
strNomeCidade = "c1"

'Loop para salvar as linhas na outra planilha, no caso, Sheet1
'Se a planilha Sheet1 estiver em branco, a primeira linha vai ficar em branco
For i = 1 To lngUltimaLinha
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = strNomeCidade Then
    Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Copy ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```